# Calculate Orthonormal Basis by Using only one vector (direction vector)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, circles, orthogonality

**Goal:** Drawing a Set of circular point around a center point in 3D space facing towards the direction vector. End Goal is to draw a Cylinder and Bend.

**Followed this approach to draw a circle 3D:** https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4089856
[how circle is drawing using Orthonormal basis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQMxH.png)
I have a Vector **V** which is `Point B - Point A` actually a direction vector. Now I have to build an Orthogonal Basis using that vector to draw a Circle facing towards **V**.

calculate Orthogonal Basis:

Taking an arbitrary vector (I think problem is here). I would get every possible combination of Direction Vector **V**, how would I know that which arbitrary vector would be best Orthogonal to the Direction Vector **V**? Obviously once I get a orthogonal vector **v1** I can get the 2nd one by using Cross product of **`V x v1`** . Thus, I would have 3 Orthogonal vectors.

[Followed Exact these Steps to Find Orthogonal basis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vPYp.png)

**Issues:**

1. There is a Rotation effect can be seen in the resulting circular points. [Check Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvCG3.png)
2. As per my understanding, the other 2 orthogonal vectors should be generated on a fixed axis for all of the points because this would affect the starting points on the points Set and hence result in a twist. [Check my other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77045582/13218380)

Is there any robust way to **draw a Circle in 3D space and pointing towards the direction vector and also should not rotate in any case** (starting and ending points should not disturb and should be in similar position as the previous Circular ring) no matter in which direction it is pointing (it will disturb the overall shape of the cylinder)?